# Replace only the beginning of a line

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am struggling with a sed command.
I am trying to achieve this:

`Input: 03:23PM`

`Output: 15:23PM`

My sed command which I have tried:

`echo $line | sed 's/03:..PM/15:..PM/g`

Comment: Technically, a 24H representation of `03:23PM` is `15:23` -- with no `PM`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remember part of the replacement test, use parentheses. To refer to the first pair of parentheses, use `\1`:

```
sed 's/03:\(..\)PM/15:\1PM/g'
```

In fact, you can make both the `:` and `PM` part of the capture group:

```
sed 's/03\(:..PM\)/15\1/g'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '/[0-9:]*[AP]M/s/^[^:]*/15/' <<< $line
15:23PM
```

Or using @dawg solution to handle multiple ranges

```
sed "/PM/s/^[^:]*/echo \$((&+12))/e" <<< $line
15:23PM
```

Comment: You might want to anchor this at the start of the line with `s/^[^:]...`

Comment: And maybe be more precise with something like`/^[0-9][0-9]*:[0-9][0-9]*[AP]M/s/^[^:]*/15/`.  But this is definitely the right approach.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `awk` so you are getting actual addition and can detect `AM` vs `PM`:

```
echo '03:23PM
11:33PM
03:23AM' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} /PM/ && $1<12 {$1=$1+12} 1'
```

Prints:

```
15:23PM
23:33PM
03:23AM
```

Comment: Awesome solution

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to handle this task in any kind of context, and taking into consideration that you only need to tackle `00`-`11` hours, you can use Perl:

```sh
perl -pe 's/(?<!\d)(0?\d|1[01])(?=:[0-5]?\d\s*PM)/$1+12/ge' file
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sw0v18/1). *Details*:

- `(?<!\d)` - no digit immediately on the left is allowed
- `(0?\d|1[01])` - Group 1 (`$1`): an optional `0` and then any one digit, or `1` and a `0` or `1` after it (`10` and `11`)
- `(?=:[0-5]?\d\s*PM)`  - a positive lookahead that requires `:`, an optional digit from `0` to `5` and then any one digit, zero or more whitespaces and `PM` substring immediately to the right of the current location.

The `$1+12` replacement is an expression that sums the found hour value with `12`.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/UpRvjX):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
text='Time: 00:23PM
Time: 03:23PM
Time: 11:23PM

Time: 12:23PM
Time: 13:45PM'
perl -pe 's/(?<!\d)(0?\d|1[01])(?=:[0-5]?\d\s*PM)/$1+12/ge' <<< "$text"
```

Output:

```
Time: 12:23PM
Time: 15:23PM
Time: 23:23PM

Time: 12:23PM
Time: 13:45PM
```